# rails issue with document.getElementById("id").focus()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Hey guys I am trying to get the **input box** to have focus when the page is loaded. So that the user can simply start typing in the box without tabbing to it. Also, if you have the coffeescript version I would love to see that also. Thanks!

I have this in mailer.js file:

```
document.getElementById("id").focus()
```

This html in the process_order.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'process_orders', :method => "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :id %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the source code of the page

```
<form action="/process?method=get" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden"  name="authenticity_token"  value="JE2OKhdKm+vgUufwB8mIcPtVQgTAktzahT1MkLGvDbVWb+b5mTuAyZ1L6ATgcWy9l8285R21Qqm KWt/BCt4/QA==" />
 <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
 </form></br>
```

Comment: Do you have that in an on document ready function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`autofocus` is a HTML5 property, it might not be supported by all browsers

You can set focus on window.onload event

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("id").focus();
}
```

here is the coffeescript version

```
window.onload = ->
  document.getElementById('id').focus()
  return
```

Comment: Ok, we are closer, it focuses on the form when I hit reload but not when I click to the link leading to that search.....

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `autofocus` attribute to your text field. Just change

```
<%= text_field_tag :id %>
```

to

```
<%= text_field_tag :id, nil, autofocus: true %>
```

and you should get the desired functionality.

Comment: yep, I knew about this command, but I was trying to work around the non html5 browsers